# Tabulator JSON return from server

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, tabulator

I am using Tabulator plugin to handle tables and sorting for me inside of a jsp page. When I use data table inside of the  tags, it works fine.  I am now attempting to return AJAX data from the system we use.  Below is a sample of the json returned by the system.

How do I configure Tabulator to use the data and skip the "platform"  part of the response?

JSP script
    table

```
<script>
//Build Tabulator
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:"311px",
    layout:"fitColumns",
    placeholder:"No Data Set",
    columns:[
        {title:"PO", field:"po_number", sorter:"string", width:200},
    ],
});

//trigger AJAX load on "Load Data via AJAX" button click    
$("#ajax-trigger").click(function(){
   table.setData("https://mysystem.com/record/fieldList=po_number&alt=json");
});
</script>
```

JSON response:

> {"platform": {
>         "message": {
>         "code": "0",
>           "description": "Success"
>         },
>         "record": [
>           {"po_number": "P000466"},
>           {"po_number": "P000791"},
>           ],
>         "recordCount": "2"
>       }}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ***ajaxResponse*** callback to alter the response before it is passed into the table for processing.

I assume you are wanting to pass in the ***record*** property:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:"311px",
    layout:"fitColumns",
    placeholder:"No Data Set",
    columns:[
        {title:"PO", field:"po_number", sorter:"string", width:200},
    ],
    ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
        //url - the URL of the request
        //params - the parameters passed with the request
        //response - the JSON object returned in the body of the response.

        return response.record; //return the recordproperty of a response json object
    },
});
```

I hope that helps,

Cheers

Oli :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url : "{{url_for('foo')}}", 
    data: {fooid:fooid},
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json;",
    success: function(receipts){var obj = $.parseJSON(receipts);
        var table = new Tabulator("#user-project-table", {
        layout:"fitData",
        data:obj,  
        etc,
        etc,
        etc...
        },
            error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
```